# Restore a db backup file in sql server 2008 r2 through command prompt

Tags: sql-server-2005, command, command-prompt

I use this command to restore a database backup file in SQL Server 2008 R2 standard edition from the command prompt:

```
SqlCmd -E -S <local> -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [test] FROM DISK = 'C:dbbackup_14'"
```

Did you manage to get any closure on what this issue was? I have the same scenario where the backup has been running fine, however overnight it failed with the same error:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot open backup device 'E:\hg_backup_20100915.bak'. Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

My server is running on Network Service account and this has full permission to the specified drive. As above, backing up to another drive works, however I do not have enough capacity to simply change the path for all databases.

This is super weird given that nothing has changed at all since the last successful backup (which was the previous night).

Thanks,
Indra

Answer (score 0):

At first blush it appears that you are missing the '\' in the path. Shouldn't it be 'C:\dbbackup_14'? If that's not it, it could be a space issue on the destination drive and keep in mind that if the database is (for example) 3GB in size, SQL Server is going want a bit more than that available to restore the database.

Hope this helps.